# Bind to both IPv4 and IPv6 loopback

Tags: node.js, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to set a sensible secure default for a server application. I want out of the box the server to only bind to the loopback interface. The user can then make their own decision to open it up to more interfaces by changing the default.

I can bind to `127.0.0.1` to get IPv4, or I can bind to `::1` to get IPv6 but I can't seem to find a way to get both.

If I don't care about just limiting it to the loopback interface I can bind to `::` which will bind to all addresses on all interfaces, but this is not a "secure by default" approach.

I can't just bind to `localhost` because from NodeJS v17 onward it will default to preferring IPv6 (or which ever is returned first by the resolver)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There is no special address representing both. I would bind to ipv4 loopback by default.

Comment: The problem with just binding to IPv4 is that another (e.g. NodeJS) client will fail to connect to it if given `localhost` and its not obvious to all but a very technical user why.

Comment: It would be very weird for someone to write client that uses ipv6 by default. I don't know a single example of such software. That being said you can always bind to everything and filter out ip at application level.

Comment: But if you try and bind to `localhost` it will now bind to IPv6 only by default...

Comment: The name `localhost` normally resolves to the IPv4 loopback address. Unless someone has custom os configuration, in which case I would say this is this person's problem. Or again: you can always do manual filtering on app level.

Comment: No it doesn't `localhost` resolves to both `127.0.0.1` and `::1` on the majority modern Linux distros by default (run `host localhost` on a ubuntu box or `Resolve-DnsName localhost` in a Windows PowerShell terminal)

Comment: Yes, but if you want to connect to it, the client has to pick one. It will almost always chose ipv4 first.

Comment: But if you want additionally to let the user know (when connection fails due to misconfiguration) then the only option is to bind to everything and to do manual IP filtering and error/warning logging.

Comment: Many server applications support binding to multiple addresses. Some applications even allow you to specify which interface(s) to listen on. Which server application are you asking about?

Comment: @SanderSteffann I'm asking how to do it with NodeJS, not a specific application (which would be off topic)

Comment: @freakish what you are saying is incorrect. Client applications connect over IPv6 by default. In operating systems that support IPv6 (which is almost all of them) the source and destination addresses are chosen based on RFC 6724 by default. Browsers usually use RFC 6555 or RFC 8395.

Comment: @SanderSteffann interesting RFC, I didn't know about it. However it does say that address A should be taken if B can be determined to be unreachable. This always can be done for localhost. Meaning it actually doesn't matter which one you chose, as long as the other one is unreachable, if I understand it correctly.